# plotting a graph of a sequence and get a dimension error

Tags: matplotlib, graph, error-handling

I'm trying to create a plot in Python to illustrate how my sequence changes as `n` grows. I get a dimension error. How can I fix this?

My code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros(101)
x[0] = 0
for n in range(0, 101):
    x[n] = x[n-1] - n
    if x[n] < 0:
        x[n] = x[n-1] + n

y = set(x)   
print(y)

i = np.linspace(0, 100)

plt.plot(y, i, 'g')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (50,)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using plt.plot with a set and because of that its saying first dimension has shape (1,). The x-argument in plt.plot should be a array-like or scalar you can read more in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) so you can convert it to a list:

```
y = list(set(x))
```

Also you need to make sure that the for each value in y there is a corresponding value in i (y and i need to be the same shape). So you need to set np.linspace to return len(y) values:

```
i = np.linspace(0, 100, len(y))
```

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros(101)
x[0] = 0
for n in range(0,101):
    x[n] = x[n-1] - n
    if x[n]<0:
        x[n] = x[n-1] + n

y = list(set(x))

i = np.linspace(0, 100, len(y))

plt.plot(y, i,'g')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]